# How to retrieve dynamically generated name tag for s:set for Struts2?

Tags: java, struts2, dynamically-generated, ognl

How can I retrieve a dynamically generated name tag for <s:set> on Struts 2?

E.g.:
In my action class I have an object (currency) that have this fields: 'id' and 'symbol'.
So in my view page I can use this:

```
<s:iterator value="currency">
    <s:set name="var_%{id}" value="symbol"/>
    <s:set name="total_%{id}" value="%{0.0}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

So I can use this to create these PageContext variables like "var_BRL", "var_USD", "var_MXN" and "total_BRL", "total_USD", "total_MXN" etc. If I write the following code:

```
<s:property value="#var_USD"/> = <s:property value="#total_USD"/>
```

I'm able to retrive a result like:

```
USD = 0.0
```

I'm using these #total_XXX variables to sum some values under some conditions presented by another iterator, in a way that I'll have at the end of this other iteraction, a result of the total spent in every currency (BRL, USD, MXN etc).

But when I try to retrieve these values dynamically, nothing is rendered. Following is the code I'm using to retrieve the values from these variables, at the end of my page. I don't understand OGNL very well, so I've tryed different arrangements like the ones below and had no success with any of them:

```
<s:iterator value="currency">
    <s:property value="#var_%{id}"/> = <s:property value="#total_%{id}"/>
    <s:property value="#%{var_%{id}}"/> = <s:property value="#%{total_%{id}}"/>
    <s:property value="%{#var_%{id}}"/> = <s:property value="%{#total_%{id}}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Is there a solution to retrieve these values in the PageContext? Or can I only solve this inside my Action? I've searched so many posts but I couldn't find anything.

Thank you!
LZ

Answer (score 0):

discussing with a friend, I found the proper OGNL expression to call for the dynamically created variables names at the end of my code:

```
<s:iterator value="currency">
    <s:property value="#attr['var_'+id]"/> = <s:property value="#attr['total_'+id]"/><br>
</s:iterator>
```